# Immediate Execute of many Files after InstallInitialize

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I want do execute many files after `InstallInitialize` but not deferred, because I can have no admin rights. Till now I used for one file the example of the documentation:

```
<Property Id="QtExecCmdLine" Value="command line to run"/>
<CustomAction Id="QtExecExample" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="QtExecExample" After="TheActionYouWantItAfter"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

But the problem is, that there is only one `QtExecCmdLine` property and I want to execute more files.

The only way I see is to use the deferred example from the documentation with two custom actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files you want to run change your system you must run them after InstallInitialize and before InstallFinalize.

You can set the Impersonate attribute to “yes” to run them as user who lunched the installer instead of the System user account

To run multiple executable files after Installinitialize:

1) Create CustomAction for each of them

```
<Fragment>
  <CustomAction Id="MYEXE1"
                   FileKey="myexe1.exe"
                   ExeCommand="-u"
                   Execute="rollback"
                   Impersonate="yes"
                   Return="check">
      </CustomAction>
      <CustomAction Id="MYEXE2"
                    FileKey="myexe2.exe"
                    ExeCommand="-i"
                    Execute="deferred"
                    Impersonate="yes"
                    Return="check">
      </CustomAction>
    </Fragment>
```

2)Schedule the custom

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="MYEXE1" After="InstallInitialize">
 <![CDATA[NOT Installed]]>
</Custom>
<Custom Action="MYEXE2" After="myexe1">
 <![CDATA[NOT Installed]]>
</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This will open a shell window for a short moment right?